# Selenium get images

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to open image src URL with this code. It doesn't show any error but nothing happens with image src too.
So can anyone help me for this ?

Code:

```
images=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')

for image in images:

    img_src=image.get_attribute('src')

    urllib2.urlopen(img_src, "/var/node/1/shantikunjtoday.png ")
```

Comment: How about if you open one img_src in browser by manual?

Comment: You are trying to extract the `src` attribute through `get_attribute('src')`. What is your exact next step?

Comment: @DebanjanB, I want to open the URL from extracted 'src' attribute ?

Comment: Check if  invoking `/var/node/1/shantikunjtoday.png` in a new (side) tab opens the _url_ as expected or else extract the `href` attribute and check with that.

Comment: @MansiMehta , "open" means open in Browser or just GET the content?

Comment: @Andersson, 'Open' means open in the browser.

Comment: `urllib2.urlopen` will not open it in this sense. Try `driver.get(img_src)` instead

Comment: @Andersson I tried with driver.get(img_src) but there is too many image src so how can I open any particular one of them ?

Comment: You need to use more specific selector instead of `driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')` to fetch only several required images

Comment: @DebanjanB This code works fine after extracting [href] attribute. Thanks.
links=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Live')

live_link= links.get_attribute("href")

driver.get(live_link)

Comment: @MansiMehta Great News !!! Glad to be able to help you out !!!